# Java string index out of bounds in for loop (codingbat function mirrorEnds)

Tags: java, string

I have a question regarding the problem at codingbat in String 3. Question is as follows:

> Given a string, look for a mirror image (backwards) string at both the
> beginning and end of the given string. In other words, zero or more
> characters at the very begining of the given string, and at the very
> end of the string in reverse order (possibly overlapping).

For example, the string "abXYZba" has the mirror end "ab"

> mirrorEnds("abXYZba") → "ab"
>
> mirrorEnds("abca") → "a"
>
> mirrorEnds("aba") → "aba"

My code is as follows:

```
public String mirrorEnds(String string) {

if(string.length() <=1) return string;  
String x = "";
int y = string.length() - 1;


for(int i = 0; i < string.length()/2; i++)
{ 
  if(string.charAt(i) == string.charAt(y))
  {
    x+= Character.toString(x.charAt(i)); 
    y--;
  }
  else
  {
    return x;
  }
  
}

return string;

}
```

When I try it for the following:

> "xxYxx"

String length is 5 so index from 0-4. If I run it on my code, the logic will be:

```
    i = 0 and y = 4;

string.charAt(i) == string.charAt(y) //true and i++ and y--
string.charAt(i) == string.charAt(y) //true and i++ and y--
//i is == string.length()/2 at this point
```

But the problem throws me an error saying indexoutofbounds. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the `i`th character of the wrong string here:

```
x += Character.toString(x.charAt(i));
```

The String `x` is empty at first, so the character at index 0 doesn't exist.

Access the original `string` instead.

```
x += Character.toString(string.charAt(i));
```

Comment: I think I am blind :). I was looking at so many other things I forgot to check the simple call...

Answer (score 0):

Here my code for this problem , simple one

```
public String mirrorEnds(String string) {

  int start = 0;
  int end = string.length()-1;

  for(int i=0;i<string.length();i++){

    if(string.charAt(start) == string.charAt(end) ){
      start++;
      end--;
    }

    if(start != ((string.length()-1)-end)){
      break;
    }


  }

  return string.substring(0,start);


}
```

Comment: It would be helpful provide some context to your code, to explain how you've solved the asker's question.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public String mirrorEnds(String string) {

     String g="";

  for(int i=0;i<string.length();i++){
 if(string.charAt(i)==string.charAt(string.length()-1-i)){

  g=g+string.charAt(i);
      } else{

  break;
  }
 }
   return g;
  }
```

Comment: I would recommend that you add some explanatory text to your answer, or you risk having it deleted as 'low quality' (even though it may be a correct answer)!

Answer (score 0):

You have a good start, but I think you should consider an even simpler approach. You only need to use one index (not both `i` and `y`) to keep track of where you are in the string because the question states that overlapping is possible. Therefore, you do not need to run your for loop until `string.length() / 2`, you can have it run for the entire length of the string.

Additionally, you should consider using a while loop because you have a clear exit condition within the problem: once the string at the beginning stops being equal to the string at the end, break the loop and return the length of the string. A while loop would also use less variables and would reduce the amount of conditional operators in your code.

Here's my answer to this problem.

```
public String mirrorEnds(String string) {
    String mirror = "";
    int i = 0;
    while (i < string.length() && string.charAt(i) == string.charAt(string.length() - i - 1) {
        mirror += string.charAt(i);
        i++;
    }
    return mirror;
}
```

Another handy tip to note is that characters can be appended to strings in Java without casting. In your first if statement within your for loop, you don't need to cast `x.charAt(i)` to a string using `Character.toString()`, you can simply append `x.charAt(i)` to the end of the string by writing `x += x.charAt(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String mirrorEnds(String str) {
  StringBuilder newStr = new StringBuilder();
  String result = "";
  
  for (int i=0; i <= str.length(); i++){
    newStr.append(str.substring(0, i));
    if (str.startsWith(newStr.toString()) && str.endsWith(newStr.reverse().toString()))
      result = str.substring(0, i);
    
    newStr.setLength(0);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: you could also take advantage of the stringbuilder class since it has the reverse method. My solution matches the start of the string with the reversed end.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please also describe what you are doing - please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
public String mirrorEnds(String string) {

    // reverse given string
    String reversed = "";
    for (int i = string.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reversed += string.charAt(i);
    }
    // loop through each string simultaneously. if substring of 'string' is equal to that of 'reversed', 
    // assign the substring to variable 'text' 
    String text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <= string.length(); i++) {
        if (string.startsWith(string.substring(0, i)) ==
                string.startsWith(reversed.substring(0, i))) {
            text = string.substring(0, i);
        }
    }
    
    return text;

}
```

Comment: This question already contains multiple answers and an accepted answer. Can you explain where your answer differs from the other answers? Also know that Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: It is similiar. The difference is that here I reversed the string first before proceeding with the rest of the solution; and also used a native 'startsWith' method, instead of direclty comparing chars, which I find a bit easier to read. Thanks for your comment. I will add more explanations when replying in the future.

Comment: why you use two for loops?

Answer (score -1):

```
public String mirrorEnds(String string) {
  String out = "";
  int len = string.length();
  for(int i=0,j = len-1;i<len;i++,j--)
  {
    if(string.charAt(i) == string.charAt(j))
      out += string.charAt(i);
    else
      break;
  } 
  return out; 
}
```

Comment: Please include some explanation of your answer, so that others can learn.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.